# Segmenting multiple elements to hide/show with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have built a semi-custom DataGrid based on a table with fields that auto-populate based on a Service call, An intended behavior in the DataGrid is the ability for the user to revise an entry in the system (in this case, Documents) so that the user can select an action and "Replace" the file, and its File Type. The actual markup looks like this:

```
<form action="#" method="post" ng-model="OtherDocumentsForm" style="margin-top: 15px;">
            <h3 style="margin: 0;">Additional Documents</h3>

            <table>
                  <tr>
                    <th>File Type</th>
                    <th>File Name</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="record in DocumentsOther track by $index" id="row-{{record.file_url}}">
                    <td>
                        <span data-document-type="{{record.file_type}}" data-document-id='{{record.document_id}}'>{{record.file_type}}</span>
                        <select ng-model="newDocumentType" id="replace-file-doctype-{{record.document_id}}" placeholder="Choose file Type" ng-show="$scope.replaceFile" data-document-id="{{record.document_id}}" class="replaceComboBox"> <!-- Note replaceFile -->
                            <option label="" value="" selected="selected"></option>
                            <option label="PDF" value="pdf">PDF</option>
                            <option label="Image" value="image">Image</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div ng-if="record">
                            <a href="{{record.file_url}}">{{record.document_name}}</a>
                            <!-- Replace Action-->
                            <button class="replaceAssociatedRecord" ng-click="ClearAssociatedFile($event, this, '{{record.file_url}}', '{{record.document_id}}');" data-document-type="{{record.file_type_raw}}">Replace</button>
                            <input type="file" ng-model="replaceFileField" id="replace-file-{{record.document_id}}" data-document-id="{{record.document_id}}" data-document-type="{{record.file_type_raw}}" onclick="checkIfAssocFileDefined(this);" ng-show="replaceFile" class="replaceFileField" /> <!-- Note replaceFile -->
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{record.date_created | dateConsistent}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <button ng-click="addUncategorizedFile($event)" style="margin: 5px auto 15px; display: block;">Upload additional file</button>
        </form>
```

As you can probably see, one of the issues that is present is that $scope.replaceFile is called across the board. This value gets set to true when $scope.ClearAssociatedFile() (code below) is called in the replace action, so *every* field gets unhidden. This was a serious oversight on my end and I am wondering, what would be the best approach to re-implement the components here so that I can split off replaceFile (tied to ng-show, and uninitalized inside the parent controller) so its independent enough to where it can be altered once the event of ClearAssociatedFile is selected?

```
$scope.ClearAssociatedFile = function(event, elem, parentClassName, inheritDocumentId) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    //TODO reconfigure to use event
    //document.getElementById("row-"+parentClassName).children[0].children[0].innerHTML = "";
    event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].children[0].innerHTML = "";
    //event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].children[1].style.display = "inline-block"

    //document.getElementById("row-"+parentClassName).children[1].children[0].children[0].innerHTML = "";
    event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[0].children[0].innerHTML = "";

    //document.getElementById("row-"+parentClassName).children[1].children[0].children[1].style.display = "none";
    event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[0].children[1].style.display = "none";
    //event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[0].children[2].style.display = "inline-block";

    //Revise the File Type field to its default.
    document.getElementById("replace-file-doctype-"+inheritDocumentId).value = event.target.attributes[2].value;

    //Show existing fields
    //eval($scope.replaceFile+inheritDocumentId = true);
    var replaceFileKey = "replaceFileItem"+$filter('convert_dashes')(inheritDocumentId);
    $scope[replaceFileKey] = true;
};
```

Comment: Just hang it off of your `record` object that is created in the `ng-repeat`. Also, instead of doing all the DOM manipulation that you are doing (which, in general, should be avoided at all costs in an Angular controller) you should pass the `record` object to the controller method and then set its properties.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, declare the following variable

```
$scope.replaceFileKeys = {};
```

Replace the last 2 lines in the `ClearAssociatedFile` function with the following

```
var replaceFileKey = inheritDocumentId;
$scope.replaceFileKeys[replaceFileKey] = true;
```

Update `ng-show` as follows

```
ng-show="$scope.replaceFileKeys[record.document_id]"
```

With the above change, only the item that you interact with is hidden. Let me now if you have questions about the change.